# List of popular protests and revolutionary movements that accepted permissionless cryptocurrency to avoid donation censorship?

Tags: history, censorship-resistance

Where can I find a list of historically-important protest and revolutionary movements that accepted bitcoin (and/or other permissionionless cryptocurrencies) as a result-of (or to preempt the risk-of) financial blockades and their accounts being frozen?

The first bitcoin wallet I ever created was in late 2011. I learned about Bitcoin as part of the Occupy Wall Street movement. As a permissionless currency, we used Bitcoin to accept donations that couldn't be blocked by the financial institutions (the same financial institutions that we were actively protesting and demanding criminal justice against their leadership). It made sense.

Even though this history is apart of living memory, I struggle to find sources of information online pinpointing the exact date Occupy Wall Street started accepting bitcoin, and why.

It's very sad that this history is being muddled. Especially because today, more-and-more people think that that Bitcoin was created as an investment vehicle for capitalists without understanding the history (that it was created as an egalitarian alternative *currency*, not a capital asset).

Where can I find a curated, well-referenced list of all the protest movements that accepted Bitcoin, including Occupy Wall Street?

Comment: occupywallst.org added bitcoin to their donation page on Nov 26, 2011 https://web.archive.org/web/20111126164538/http://occupywallst.org/donate/

Comment: #FeedTheProtest published their bitcoin address on Sep 27 2011 in response to PayPal blocking withdrawals of their donations https://web.archive.org/web/20111004164350/http://feedtheprotest.com/node/223

Comment: I created a community wiki where others can add relevant things. I added a few that I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Movements

- #FeedTheProtest in [Sep 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20111004164350/http://feedtheprotest.com/node/223)
- occupywallst.org in [Nov 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20111126164538/http://occupywallst.org/donate/)
- [freeross.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206175448/http://freeross.org/) in [2013](https://dallas.culturemap.com/news/city-life/11-21-13-silk-road-ross-ulbricht-bitcoin-charges-legal-fund-freeross-org)
- Hong Kong [2020](https://www.coindesk.com/policy/2020/03/05/with-freedom-at-stake-more-hongkongers-see-bitcoins-unique-value/)
- Ukraine in [2022](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2022/03/03/donate-ukraine-money-crypto/)
- [Palestine](https://web.archive.org/web/20231018182436/https://www.savethechildren.org/us/where-we-work/west-bank-gaza) in [2023](https://web.archive.org/web/20231019175214/https://www.unrwausa.org/crypto)

### Organizations

Also consider the following organizations that used cryptocurrenices

- WikiLeaks in [June 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110627061856/http://blogs.forbes.com/andygreenberg/2011/06/14/wikileaks-asks-for-anonymous-bitcoin-donations/)
- Backpage in [2015](https://reason.com/2018/08/21/backpage-founders-larkin-and-lacey-speak/) <sub>In 2015 [Backpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpage) lost all credit card processing agreements as banks came under pressure from law enforcement, leaving Bitcoin as the remaining option for paid ads</sub>

Comment: that's pretty US-centric. What about popular protest movements in Asia? The Middle-East? Africa? South America? Europe? Also, WikiLeaks and Backpage aren't protest movements. Please remove them or at least add them to a different section

Comment: I am from Asia but I don't remember any protests that were prevented by governments and people accepted bitcoin. Trying this since 2015 although I cannot write something that never happened.

Comment: Hong Kong 2019?

Comment: Wikileaks and Backpage were forced to look for other payments when paypal, etc. was banned so I cannot remove them.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield yes, sorry I missed it and one of the reasons I created `community-wiki`

Comment: I still haven't found any articles about bitcoin being used to collect donations for the 2019 protests in HK, but here's an article about HSBC freezing their account after it got ~9 million USD in donations https://hongkongfp.com/2019/12/20/four-hong-kong-protester-support-group-arrestees-released-bail/

Comment: I'm curious if there's also evidence of bitcoin being used by protest movements in Lebanon in 2020 and Iran in 2022.

Comment: To find more, I'd be curious to look for spikes of activity on websites for otc trading like localbitcoins in specific regions, then see if those spikes coorelate in time with news articles about protests and social unrest in those regions.